# Creating admin page in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am considering best option to create multi-purpose admin page in my asp.net application. In that section should be searching users in database, adding users, review single users or whole groups, etc. I have two ways, how to do it:

1. create single page for every option. It means: on first page will be some text box and search button, on second will be form with multiple textboxes to add new user, and so on.
2. place all needed controls to one page. Then use query string (something like aspx?mode=userAdd) to determine desired task and hide unneeded controls.

Please, give me best idea, which one is better. (Or maybe you know completely different approach).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between the two options presented, #1 is probably better -- at least you won't have to deal with the horrors of maintaining state between 2 dozen disparate options and other added bonuses such as multi-megabyte viewstate fields.

The best solution is probably somewhere in the middle and really depends on your use cases and what makes sense to have together. In most cases this has little to do with the way it was programmed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about those viewstate fields. However it will be little strange to have many same pages, which variates only in 1 or 2 controls

Comment: Option #1 is the best bet, if you combine it with option #2 just like @Wyatt says

Comment: OK, thanks guys. I am begining with asp.net, so I want to produce comprehensible code and website structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best option is create a MasterPage, an differents aspx, so is more organized.
But it always will depends of many pages do you have to create; anyway I think the second option is not the best.

Two interesting links about MasterPages:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/How-to-Use-Master-Pages/